# key-many-to-one and key-property association: nhibernate won't DELETE items from set

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, composite-id

I'll try to keep this terse, but hopefully won't miss any important information in my troubles.  The code I believe provides all details, but I've left out the noise (it's VB, so there's lots of noise :) ).

A "Case" object has many "Assignments":

```
Public Class Case
  Property CaseId As Guid 
  Property Assignments As ISet(Of CaseAssignment)
End Class

Public Class CaseAssignment
  Property Case As Case
  Property RoleId As Guid
End Class
```

The data model I've been handed looks about like what you'd expect, except CaseAssignment is a composite key:

```
table Case
   CaseId uniqueid not null primary key
   ...

table CaseAssignment
   CaseId uniqueid not null
   RoleId uniqueid not null
   PK := (CaseId, RoleId)
   FK from CaseId -> Case.CaseId
```

Finally, the Fluent NHibernate Mappings:

```
Class CaseMapping
  Public Sub New()
    Table("Case")
    KeyColumn("CaseId")
    HasMany(Function(x) x.Assignments).KeyColumn("CaseId").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
End Class

Class CaseAssignmentMapping
  Public Sub New()
    Table("CaseAssignment")
    CompositeId() _
      .KeyReference(Function(x) x.Case, "CaseId") _
      .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.RoleId)
End Class
```

KeyReference correlates with "key-many-to-one" in the XML mapping lingo.

When I add assignments to a case all is good, but when I remove references I get one of two problems.  With this code:

```
aCase.Assignments.Remove(someAssignment)
caseRepository.Save(aCase)
```

The error I get back is, "Could not delete collection rows... Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CaseId', table 'CaseAssignments'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated."  This was from trying to issue the following SQL:

```
UPDATE CaseAssignments SET CaseId = null
WHERE CaseId = @p0 AND RoleId = @p1 AND CaseId = @p2
@p0=[valid guid #1],
@p1=[valid guid #2],
@p2=[valid guid #1 again] **!?!**
```

So that's a little messed up.  So I try this code:

```
aCase.Assignments.Remove(someAssignment)
someAssignment.Case = Nothing
caseRepository.Save(aCase)
```

and the error is "Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1" because NHibernate tried to:
DELETE FROM CaseAssignments WHERE RoleId = [valid guid] AND CaseId = **NULL**

I've been scouring threads and forums and the NHibernate and Hibernate docs and haven't really come across anything similar yet.  Hopefully it's something simple.  Thanks to anyone who takes a shot at this one!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago. The solution is to put the "inverse" attribute to "true" on your collection of CaseAssignments in your CaseMapping class. Like this:

```
HasMany(Function(x) x.Assignments).KeyColumn("CaseId").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse()
```

As far as I know, you must have both the AllDeleteOrphan cascade type AND the Inverse property set to true for this to work.

I hope it works!

Comment: Ditto to Groxx, but for a simpler situation with a non-composite key.